# where does the array elements get stored when we use shift in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried array.shift() and array.unshift().
As a beginner in javascript I am not able to understand if use shift(), first array element will get removed but when we use unshift after shift from where does the removed element get added?

```
var temp = ['Five','Four','Three']
// temp.shift()
temp.unshift()
console.log(`we have ${temp}`)
```

This is a sample snippet

Comment: Um...you probably left `temp.shift()` commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.unshift` adds the element to first position in the array. Pls see below example.

Always better to read [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) as well

```js
let arr = ['Five','Four','Three']

arr.unshift('add1')

console.log(arr)
```

Also, `Array.shift` removes first element from the array

```js
let arr1 = ['Five','Four','Three']

arr1.shift()

console.log(arr1)
```

**UPDATE** - Doing `shift` and `unshift` parallelly to show `unshift()` without passing any value does nothing.

```js
let arr1 = ['Five','Four','Three']

arr1.shift()

arr1.unshift()

console.log(arr1)
```

Comment: If i use shift first on array consisting 5 element it will remove first element. But after shift() If I call unshift() without any parameter it retrieves the removed element. My question is from where does it retrieve the deleted values?

Comment: It never happens. If you do `unshift` without passing any value.. it's sort of doing nothing.

Comment: So, when you say you do `shift()` and then `unshift()` your value comes back.. it doesn't happen.. I will update answer for you

Comment: @JitendraKoyande Updated

Comment: Updated my solution. you can see unshift() does nothing.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the quick reply. @NishantNarang